# Use the integration of Gauss-Legendre for find the exact value

Tags: numerical-methods

Use the integration of Gauss-Legendre for find the exact value of $$\int_{0}^{1}(x^7+2x^2-1)dx$$

Is obvious the exact value is $\dfrac{-5}{24}$. If $[0,1]\to [-1,1]$, we have $y=2x-1\to x=\dfrac{y+1}{2}$, and $$\int_{0}^{1}(x^7+2x^2-1)dx=\int_{1}^{1}{\left(\left(\dfrac{y+1}{2}\right)^7+2\left(\dfrac{y+1}{2}\right)^2-1\right)\dfrac{dy}{2}}$$

But how I use the Gauss-Legendre integration? Until index n???. The legendre polynomials are $p_{n}(x)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n}n!}\dfrac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}[(1-x^2)^n]$, and  $A_{i}=\dfrac{2}{(1-x_{i}^2)[p'_{n}(x_{i})]^{2}}$. Any Hint pls!! Regards

Answer (score 0):

For the Gauss-Legendre quadrature with $n$ nodes (and for others Gauss-type quadratures) the error estimate is given by
$$
\varepsilon \sim C_n (b-a)^{2n+1} f^{(2n)}(\xi), \; \xi \in [a, b]
$$
If you take $n \geq 4$, then the error estimate would be exactly zero, since your integrand is a polynomial of degree $7$.

Now just apply [4-point Gaussian-Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss.E2.80.93Legendre_quadrature) rule and get the answer.